# SQLITE database Uploading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

Is there any way to upload , download to a server read the .sqlite file present in document directory from your iPhone application and use it as your database.
I tried by converting to binary data and uploading but the file is getting encrypted I cannot read or write it after restoring/downloading it from server.
Any suggestion?

Uploading task fetching the file

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *chatDatabasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ChatDB.sqlite"];
NSString *contactDatabasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ContactDB.sqlite"];
NSURL*ChatDB_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:chatDatabasePath];
NSURL*ContactDB_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:contactDatabasePath];
self.ChatDBData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ChatDB_url];
self.ContactDBData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ContactDB_url];
```

Uploading

```
-(void)UploadDbToServer:(NSData*)DB_Data ForDbName:(NSString*)dbName forExtension:(NSString*)extension andCallback:(void (^)(id))callback{

NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@chat-backup-upload",baseUrl]];
urlString=[urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:100];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";
// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add DB data
if (DB_Data) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"DB\"; filename=\"%@.%@\"\r\n",dbName,extension] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: file/sqlite\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:DB_Data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConf = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConf];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    id jsonResponse= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    callback ((id) jsonResponse);
}];

[task resume];}
```

Downloading

```
(void)startDownload:(NSURL*)url {
NSURL *Url= [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];

self.activeUrlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Url];
if (!self.session) {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"image"];
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:queue];
}

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:Url];

self.task = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];

[self.task resume];}
```

Writing the downloaded file

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {

//saving the files
NSData *DBData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *chatDatabasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ChatDB.sqlite"];
NSString *contactDatabasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ContactDB.sqlite"];

if ([self.activeDownload isEqualToString:@"chat"]){

    [DBData writeToFile:chatDatabasePath atomically:YES];
    self.activeDownload = @"contact";
    [self startDownload:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",pingovaURL,self.ContactDB_URL]]];
}else{
    [DBData writeToFile:contactDatabasePath atomically:YES];   }}
```

Comment: Nothing should prevent this if you are uploading the file from within the iOS app that owns the document directory and the SQLite file. Share some code please, maybe it has a bug?

Comment: @battlmonstr sure

Comment: @battlmonstr i have edited the post and added my code please check

Comment: Could you run a couple of tests? First, determine which step is wrong, and if the file gets broken after upload or after download: do `shasum` on the file before uploading, then do it on the server after uploading, then do it after downloading and saving again, and compare. It must match if the file is transferred correctly.

A second idea is that if you are using WAL mode of SQLite, you also need to get a log file for each db, or else it won't work (usually called like ChatDB.sqlite-wal).

Comment: ok @battlmonstr

Comment: The File is getting broken after downloading the way of handling the downloaded file is not right @battlmonstr

Comment: could you please tell me something about shasum and WAL mode of sqlite@battlmonstr

Comment: [logging] file is encrypted or is not a database this error I am getting after complete process @battlmonstr

Comment: Usually sqlite database consists of 2 files: x.sqlite and x.sqlite-wal. So check if you have the "-wal" file originally on device (before uploading). If it is not there - it is not the problem.

Also check if the file is corrupted during the download or save to disk. You can extract the file from device after download and compare it with the original file (before upload). "shasum" is just a way to compare files. You can use "diff" as well.

If you think the download/save code is bad, please post the full download/save code so that we can see.

Comment: There is no x.sqlite-wal file.I checked the file in server the file is working.
After narrowing it down I came to conclusion that replacing the old DB with new DB (.sqlite) file is the challenge can you help me with that  before hand I am not using Core Data @battlmonstr

Comment: I can't help, because the download and save code that you have shared looks fine, but it is not complete (no full class is shared).

Comment: @battlmonstr https://gist.github.com/harshsrivastavaglobussoft/130cf67c7ee8882bdea42c66a697627c check this gist (upload part)

https://gist.github.com/harshsrivastavaglobussoft/384d88ccdf62b2aa05a2042be243a530 check this gist(downloading part)